# I want to nest include files inside include files. Why cant I do that in Inno Setup?

Tags: preprocessor, inno-setup, preprocessor-directive

So lets say I have a Inno Setup file (let's call it `master.iss`) with a files section like this:

```
[Files]
#include PathToIncludeFile\IncludeFile.iss
```

That works beautiful and fine. The content of `IncludeFile.iss` is effectively inserted into the `master.iss` file where the `#include` exists.

So now I want the content of the `#include` file to me nested in more includes. So the `IncludeFile.iss` looks like this:

```
#include C:\PathToFile\FileWithRealFilesDataForProject1.iss
#include C:\PathToFile\FileWithRealFilesDataForProject2.iss
#include C:\PathToFile\FileWithRealFilesDataForProject3.iss
#include C:\PathToFile\FileWithRealFilesDataForProject4.iss
#include C:\PathToFile\FileWithRealFilesDataForProject5.iss
#include C:\PathToFile\FileWithRealFilesDataForProject6.iss
```

The compiler for Inno Setup compiling `Master.iss` will say

> (File: PathToIncludeFile\IncludeFile.iss \n Line 1: \n Column 11:)
>   [ISSP] Undeclaired Identifier C"

I suppose I could achieve what I want with a batch file or something, but it would be a lot more straight forward if I could just do this with nested `#include`s.

BTW: My current Inno Setup Compiler is 5.5.6 (u)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can nest include files.**

---

Your problem is that in Inno Setup preprocessor the string literals must be enclosed in double-quotes (or single-quotes), like:

```
#include "C:\PathToFile\FileWithRealFilesDataForProject1.iss"
```

When you omit the quotes, the preprocessor tries to interpret the `#include` argument as an expression. Hence it treats the `C` (leading alphanumeric sequence) as an identifier.

See these topics in Inno Setup Preprocessor documetation:

- [Expression Syntax](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=expressions).
- [#include](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=include) directive

---

For the same reason, your primary include, the way you have it in your post, won't compile either. You must have enclosed it in double quotes.

For this:

```
#include PathToIncludeFile\IncludeFile.iss
```

I'm getting

> [ISPP] Undeclared identifier: "PathToIncludeFile".

(as expected)